# Object as key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have this class:

```
class A {
    string name;
    string code;
}
```

Examples:

```
A1: name="blabla", code="kuku"
A2: name="blabla", code=null
A3: name=null, code="kuku"

Dictionary<A, string> d=new Dictionary<A, string>();

d[A1]="aaa";
d[A2]="bbb"
results: d[A1]="bbb";

d[A1]="aaa";
d[A3]="bbb"
results: d[A1]="bbb";

d[A2]="aaa";
d[A3]="bbb"
results: d[A2]="aaa"; d[A3]="bbb";
```

Is there a way to implement class A as a Key to dictionary?

Comment: That definition doesn't even make sense.  How does (2) equal (3)?

Comment: This doesn't make sense...in what way does 2 equal 3?

Comment: Objects with the same properties are usually considered equal, thus having the same hash code. What you're saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: @all: I don't need the same name and code in order to say that the objects are equals. Somethimes the user will supply only name, somtimes he will supply only code and sometimes he will supply both.

Comment: @Naor: Then how does #2=#3 without considering #1 as an intermediate step?

Comment: @Adam Robinson: #2 is never equals to #3. I will update the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Naor: If 1=2 and 1=3, then 2 **must equal** 3 if you're using a key-based container.

Comment: But this is real life example! The user doesn't have both name and code, the user sometimes have code and sometimes have name. How can I solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your edited question:

Make two different string dictionaries (one for Name and one for Code) and search whichever one you have a value for.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

`Equals` / `GetHashCode` implementations must form an [equivalence relation] - they must satisfy the following properties:

- a == a. (Reflexivity)
- if a == b then b == a. (Symmetry)
- if a == b and b == c then a == c. (Transitivity)

Your definition is not transitive; `(a, b)` == `(b, c)` and `(b, c)` == `(c, d)` but `(a, b)` != `(c, d)`.

Comment: Why Equals/GetHashCode implementations must form an equivalence relation?

Comment: @Naor: Strictly speaking, they don't *have* to; you're free to return any value in these functions just like any other; you could make the output random if you want to. However, this behavior would be wildly unintuitive and would probably blow up on you.

Comment: Actually, it is possible if GetHashCode() return the same value all the time. But it's not good programming.

Comment: @h3xStream: It's not possible to implement this business logic in a container like this.

Comment: ...you can forget my previous comment :) it simply doesn't apply to Dictionnary.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than implementing `GetHashCode`, a better option would be to implement your own `IEqualityComparer<A>` and pass that to the constructor for your dictionary. That being said, your rules for equivalence don't make sense. Equivalence in programming must follow standard algebraic equivalence rules.

In your case, you have three objects that are considered "equal", which seems to be based on whether or not one of two properties is equal. However, this approach doesn't provide for transitive equality, which is required. #1=#2 because of the name. #1=#3 because of the code. However, equality and equivalence requires that if a=b and b=c, then a=c. In your case, comparing #2 to #3 shows no equivalence or equality since they have no matching properties, even though they're both equal to #1.

**The short version is that your rules for equality/equivalence cannot be used with any key-based repository, such as `Dictionary`.**

If you're convinced that this is the right way to go, then this will do what you're looking for, **but this will not behave consistently. Nothing can behave consistently using this pseudo-equivalence**.

```
class AEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        return x == y || x.name == y.name || x.code == y.code;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A x)
    {
        return -1; // impossible to compute; will negatively impact performance
    }
}

...

Dictionary<A, string> dict = new Dictionary<A, string>(new AEqualityComparer());
```

However, it's very easy to break this:

```
dict[A1] = "foo";
dict[A2] = "bar";

// dict[A1] is now "bar", as expected

dict[A3] = "baz";
```

Here, `dict[A1]` is `"baz"`, as expected. However, `dict[A2]` is *also* `"baz"`, even though `A2` is not equal to `A3` according to these rules. This is because the original object used was `A1`, which is equal to both.